# StreamingQueryException: Text data source supports only a single column

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I know this question has already been asked before multiple times but none of the answers help in my case.

Below is my spark code

```
class ParseLogs extends java.io.Serializable {    
def formLogLine(logLine: String): (String,String,String,Int,String,String,String,Int,Float,String,String,Flo at,Int,String,Int,Float,String)={

//some logic

//return value
(recordKey._2.toString().replace("\"", ""),recordKey._3,recordKey._4,recordKey._5,recordKey._6,recordKey._8,sbcId,recordKey._10,recordKey._11,recordKey._12,recordKey._13.trim(),LogTransferTime,contentAccessed,OTT,dataTypeId,recordKey._14,logCaptureTime1)

}
}


 val inputDf = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
  .option("subscribe", topic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()
  val myDf = inputDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

  val df1 = myDf.map(line =>  new ParseLogs().formLogLine(line.get(0).toString()))
```

I get below error

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Text data source supports only a single column, and you have 17 columns.;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UDF to convert logLine to what you want.For example:

```
    spark.sqlContext.udf.register("YOURLOGIC", (logLine: String) => {
    //some logic
    (recordKey._2.toString().replace("\"",""),recordKey._3,recordKey._4,recordKey._5,recordKey._6,recordKey._8,sbcId,recordKey._10,recordKey._11,recordKey._12,recordKey._13.trim(),LogTransferTime,contentAccessed,OTT,dataTypeId,recordKey._14,logCaptureTime1)
    })
    val inputDf = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .load()
    val myDf = inputDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    val df1 = myDf.selectExpr("YOURLOGIC(value) as result")
    val result = df1.select(
    df1("result").getItem(0),
    df1("result").getItem(1),
    df1("result").getItem(2)),
    df1("result").getItem(3)),
    ...if you have 17 item,then add to 17
    df1("result").getItem(17))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am trying your suggestion, for some reason it's giving me following error "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Field name should be String Literal, but it's 1" . Seems like it does not allow to get Item index wise, do you know the reason why? Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome.My spark version is spark-sql 2.4.0 version.  Maybe you should use String "1" for index in your spark version. Or you can upgrade to spark-sql-2.4.0 version.

Comment: I just find another way.Try this: ```     df1.selectExpr("result[0]","result[1]","result[2]")     ```

Comment: thanks again! I solved it using column name. Now I have another problem, while writing the dataframe using writestream it again gives me same error "Text data source supports only a single column, and you have.." it's like back to square one :(

Comment: Can you give me your complete code?My email is yuanp0813@163.com.

Comment: sure, I've emailed you

Comment: Have you received my reply yet?